# Delete function in Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

So I have made a CRUD in Yii and at first, I autogenerated the code using Gii but had to change the look and feel of the CRUD.

This is inside a table where I want to allow the user to delete an item:

`<a class="" title="" data-id="1718" href="index.php?r=crm/proposal/<?php array('url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$data->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-1x pos-relative"></i>Delete</a>`

The auto generation created access rules:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('delete'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        )
    );
}
```

And lastly here is the delete function:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('@'));
}
```

For some reason when I click on delete link on the page it doesn't delete. It just reloads and does nothing.

Comment: The `accessRules()` method looks more like Yii 1.x, are you sure you are using Yii 2?

Comment: Also this `<a>` element does not make sense at all - you have array declaration that is never used.